# AttributeError: 'OrdinalEncoder' object has no attribute 'category_mapping'

Tags: scikit-learn, categories, encoder, ordinal

When I use the following function, I get the `AttributeError`.

```py
from category_encoders import OrdinalEncoder

def label_encode(input_data, col):
    name = col +'_encoded'
    encoder = OrdinalEncoder(return_df=True, handle_unknown='ignore')
    input_data[name] = encoder.fit_transform(input_data[col].values).values - 1
    encoder = dict(encoder.category_mapping[0]['mapping'])
    return input_data, encoder, name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check if `category_mapping` shows up when you run `dir(encoder)` if it does not appears in the list you might be using the sklearn version of the encoder instead of the scikit-learn-contrib OrdinalEncoder.

When I run the `dir(encoder)` command the category_mapping attribute appears:

```
[ ...
 'category_mapping',
 'cols',
 'drop_cols',
 'drop_invariant',
 'feature_names',
 'fit',
 'fit_transform',
 'get_feature_names',
 'get_params',
 'handle_missing',
 'handle_unknown',
 'inverse_transform',
 'mapping',
 'ordinal_encoding',
 'return_df',
 'set_params',
 'transform',
 'verbose']
```

If you run this snippet it should display the mapping:

```py
from category_encoders import *
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
bunch = load_boston()
y = bunch.target
X = pd.DataFrame(bunch.data, columns=bunch.feature_names)
enc = OrdinalEncoder(cols=['CHAS', 'RAD']).fit(X, y)
numeric_dataset = enc.transform(X)
enc.category_mapping[0]['mapping']
```

```py
0.0    1
1.0    2
NaN   -2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Exactly. I could not see the `category_mapping` attribute when I run dir(encoder).

Comment: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/category_encoders
I installed category_encoders in my conda environment using this command `conda install -c conda-forge category_encoders`. How can I correct this mistake?

Comment: And, to install sklearn, I used `conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn`

Comment: The installation with conda is Ok, maybe the problem was that you were importing the OrdinalEncoder from scikit somewhere in the code and it overrides the OrdinalEncoder from  category_encoders.

Comment: To be certain try 
```>>> OrdinalEncoder.__module__```
It prints something like this when using the sklearn ecoder
```'sklearn.preprocessing._encoders'```
Or this when using category_encoders ```'category_encoders.ordinal'```